# Fingerprint mismatch only for 32-bit DLL linked statically to FIPS Capable OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, fips

**Appreciate any help on the following.**

1. Built OpenSSL Fips Module and then 'static binaries' of FIPS capable OSSL which 'statically link to the windows run-time'.
   Thus, my application binary (`FipsApp.exe`) does not depend on OSSL DLLs.
2. Consumed these static binaries namely (`libeaycompat32.lib`, `libeayfips32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib`) into `myapp.dll` using `msincore.pl`.
3. `FipsApp.exe` calls function `foo()` inside `myapp.dll` which executes `FIPS_mode_set()` which returns `(100:error:2D06B06F:lib(45):func(107): reason (111):/FIPS/FIPS.c:232)`

## Result

1. On executing 64-bit `FipsApp.exe`, the FIPS mode gets set and working with 64-bit `myapp.dll`
2. But on executing 32-bit `FipsApp.exe` which uses 32-bit `myapp.dll` with same configuration, `FIPS_mode_set()` fails with reason `111` (`Fingerprint mismatch`)

## Attempted

Since above 32-bit myapp.dll did not work, some additional configuration
changes were made.

1. ReBuilt 32-bit myapp.dll with above LFLAGS "`/DynamicBase:No
   /Fixed`". Here default base address gets used for myapp.dll
2. ReBuilt 32-bit myapp.dll with base address of `0xFB00000`.
   (OSSL does same thing for FIPS dlls)
3. Checking out following
   http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/FIPS-Static-Library-linked-into-Win32-Dll-builds-but-fails-self-test-td63011.html

But 32-bit myapp DLL does always fail with fingerprint mismatch.

## Question

How do I get 32-bit `myapp.dll` working in FIPS mode?
`FIPS_mode_set()` returns `(100:error:2D06B06F:lib(45):func(107): reason (111):/FIPS/FIPS.c:232)`

Thanks.

Comment: Can't help with specifics, but some general questions: **(a)** Was the 32-bit (not 34-bit!) binary run on a 64-bit version of Windows or a 32-bit one? **(b)** It would probably give a different error, but was there any possibility that the 32-bit binary was trying to load the 64-bit DLL?

Comment: hi TripleHound, for a) I have corrected the typo, was running 32-bit app on 32-bit Windows. b) 32-bit dll gets loaded and FIPS_mode_set() gets executed to fail with reason 111 (fingerprint mismatch) Thank you.